# TSQL Conditional joins & referencing table dimensions

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to find out how long a sales opportunity lasts in each one of 5 different Stages. The problem consists of flattening data in salesforce. The current structure is below:

Table: OppHistory

```
TaskID | OppID | STAGE | IQ | DISCO | TECH | COMMERCIAL | CLOSE
  1     Op1       IQ       5     0      0        0          0
  2     Op1       DISCO    0     10     0        0          0
  3     Op1       TECH     0     0      15       0          0
  4     Op1       COMM     0     0      0        5          0
  5     Op2       IQ       2     0      0        0          0  
  6     Op2       CLOSE    0     0      0        0          3
  7     Op3       IQ       3     0      0        0          0
```

The above table has ~ 417k rows. There have only ever been 49k individual opportunities created, thus 49k is the target row count for my table.

I've tried the below joins. I feel as if I'm on the 1 yd line just need a push

The below gives me a table with 39M rows

```
SELECT a.OpportunityID, b.IQ, c.Disco, d.Tech, e.Commercial, f.Close
FROM OppHistory a
  JOIN OppHistory b ON a.OppID = b.OppID
  JOIN OppHistory c ON b.OppID = c.OppID
  JOIN OppHistory d ON c.OppID = d.OppID
  JOIN OppHistory e ON d.OppID = e.OppID
  JOIN OppHistory f ON e.OppID = f.OppID
```

The below gives me a table with ~50k rows, however, only a select few opportunities are included, and each OppID is repeated around 500 times

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.OpportunityID, b.IQ, c.Disco, d.Tech, e.Commercial, 
f.Close
FROM OppHistory a
  JOIN OppHistory b ON a.OppID = b.OppID
  JOIN OppHistory c ON b.OppID = c.OppID
  JOIN OppHistory d ON c.OppID = d.OppID
  JOIN OppHistory e ON d.OppID = e.OppID
  JOIN OppHistory f ON e.OppID = f.OppID
```

The below gives me 0 results in my table

```
SELECT b.OppID, Duration AS IQDuration, Duration AS DiscoDuration, 
Duration AS TEDuration, Duration AS CommercialsDuration, Duration AS 
ClosedDuration
FROM OppHistory b,( 
    SELECT q.IQ AS Duration FROM OppHistory q
     UNION
    SELECT d.Disco AS Duration FROM OppHistory d
     UNION
    SELECT t.Tech AS Duration FROM OppHistory t
     UNION
    SELECT c.Comm AS Duration FROM OppHistory c
     UNION
    SELECT l.Closed AS Duration FROM OppHistory l
    )a
```

What I need is to have the duration per individual stage in separate columns for distinct opportunity:

```
OppID |IQ | Disco | TechEval | Commercial | Close
 Op1    5     10       15         5          0
 Op2    2     0        0          0          3
 Op3    3     0        0          0          0
```

Comment: Is this not just a simple GROUP BY query?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after this:

```
SELECT OppID, SUM(IQ) AS IQ, SUM(Disco) AS Disco, SUM(Tech) AS Tech, SUM(Commercial) AS Commercial, SUM(Close) AS Close
FROM OppHistory
GROUP BY OppID
```

Comment: Thanks Barney - this worked. Looks like i was WAY overthinking it